# Python: Split a string by a word which contains a substring

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, split

I have a string `text = "Fix me a meeting in 2 days"`. 
I have a list of some words `meetingStrings`.
`"meet"` is there in `meetingStrings`. So, I have to split the text by meeting.

Desired Output :

> in 2 days

```
meetingStrings = [
    "appointment",
    "meet",
    "interview"
]
text = "Fix me a meeting in 2 days"
for x in meetingStrings:
    if x in text.lower(): 
        txt = text.split(x, 1)[1]
        print(txt)
```

This gives Output:

> ing in 2 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `re.split()`:

```
import re

meetingStrings = [
    "appointment",
    "meet",
    "interview"
]

text = "Fix me a meeting in 2 days"

print(re.split('|'.join(r'(?:\b\w*'+re.escape(w)+r'\w*\b)' for w in meetingStrings), text, 1)[-1])
```

Prints:

```
 in 2 days
```

Comment: Hi @Andrej thanks for your answer, but my desired output is "in 2 days"

Comment: The question isn't quite clear, but I suspect that the desired output is `['Fix me a', 'in 2 days']`

Answer (score 1):

With a small change to your code:

```
meetingStrings = [
    "appointment",
    "meet",
    "interview"
]
text = "Fix me a meeting in 2 days"
for x in meetingStrings:
    if x in text.lower():
        txt = text.split(x, 1)[1]
        print(txt.split(" ", 1)[1]) #<--- Here
```

Just take your final output, and split at the first occurrence of a space

Answer (score 1):

This expression might also work with an `i` flag:

```
(?:meet|interview|appointment)\S*\s+((?:in|after)\s[0-9]+\s+(?:days?|months?|weeks?|years?))
```

and we can include any desired words that we might want in the non-capturing groups using logical ORs, such as:

```
(?:in|after|on|from)
```

---

```
(?:days?|months?|weeks?|years?|hours?)
```

---

```
(?:meet|interview|appointment|session|schedule)
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(?:meet|interview|appointment)\S*\s+((?:in|after)\s[0-9]+\s+(?:days?|months?|weeks?|years?))"
test_str = "Fix me a meeting in 2 days meetings in 2 months meet in 1 week nomeeting in 2 days meet after 2 days"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE))
```

#### Output

```
['in 2 days', 'in 2 months', 'in 1 week', 'in 2 days', 'after 2 days']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bBRYwj/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: but that doesn't include the `meetingStrings` alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import re
text = "Fix me a meeting in 2 days"
print(re.split("({})\\w*".format("|".join(meetingStrings)), text)[-1].strip())
```

Outputs: `in 2 days`

Answer (score 0):

Without Regex, **`str.partition`**-ing:

```
for x in meetingStrings: 
    pre, _, post = text.lower().partition(x) 
    if post: 
        pre = pre.rpartition(' ')[0] if not pre.endswith(' ') else pre.rstrip() 
        post = post.partition(' ')[-1] if not post.startswith(' ') else post.lstrip() 
        print([pre, post])
```

**Example:**

```
In [35]: meetingStrings = [ 
    ...:     "appointment", 
    ...:     "meet", 
    ...:     "interview" 
    ...: ] 
    ...: text = "Fix me a meeting in 2 days" 

    ...: for x in meetingStrings: 
    ...:     pre, _, post = text.lower().partition(x) 
    ...:     if post: 
    ...:         pre = pre.rpartition(' ')[0] if not pre.endswith(' ') else pre.rstrip() 
    ...:         post = post.partition(' ')[-1] if not post.startswith(' ') else post.lstrip() 
    ...:         print([pre, post]) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
['fix me a', 'in 2 days']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import re

meetingStrings = [
        "appointment",
        "meet",
        "interview"
]
text = "Fix me a meeting in 2 days"

def split_string(text, strings):
    search = re.compile('|'.join(strings))
    start = None
    input = text.split()
    for e, x in enumerate(input):
        if search.search(x):
            if start < e:
                yield ' '.join(input[start:e])
            start = None
        else:
            if start is None:
                start = e
    else:
        if start is not None:
            yield ' '.join(input[start:])

print(' '.join(split_string(text, meetingStrings)))
```

This might be longer, than other answers, but seems to do **exactly** what you wanted - split on strings, which contain as substring one of strings passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative and much simpler approach, first split all the words in your sentence then chop off the sentence from the location that `meetingStrings` appear:

```
l=text.split()
for i in meetingStrings:
    for idx, j in enumerate(l):
        if i in j:
            l=l[idx+1:] 
print(' '.join(l))
```

Gives:

```
'in 2 days'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use find() and list slice:

```
text = "Fix me a meeting in 2 days"
meetingStrings = [
    "appointment",
    "meet",
    "interview"
]


sep = [i for i in meetingStrings if i in text]

idx = text.find(sep[0])
idx_ = text[idx:].find(' ')
print (text[idx+idx_:])
```

output:

```
in 2 days
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for using a search.
All you need to do is put the text in the middle of a word
then match the word.

The result is in capture group 1.

***No whitespace trim***

`\b\w*(?:appointment|meet|interview)\w*\b(.*)`

https://regex101.com/r/lK4zRz/1

Readable version

```
 \b 
 \w* 
 (?:
      appointment
   |  meet
   |  interview
 )
 \w* 
 \b 
 ( .* )                        # (1)
```

---

***With whitespace trim***

`(?m)\b\w*(?:appointment|meet|interview)\w*\b[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*$`

https://regex101.com/r/v2qAOQ/1

---

Additionally, if you add a `.*` to the beginning of either regex,
it will always get the last keyword.